# Internet explorer Absolute positioned element bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position, haslayout

G'day,

I'm getting really weird behavior on IE (8/7/6) for an absolutely positioned element. It is styled as:

```
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 5000;
```

and the `<body>` has a vertical scrollbar.

When the page is first rendered, the absolute positioned div is rendered such that the 5 pixels are taken from the edge of the `<body>` element. But whenever there is a `:hover` or AJAX event in the body, the absolutely positioned element is re-rendered and now the 5 pixels are taken from the edge of the *scrollbar*!

The markup/css is too big/complicated to post here, but I've attached some screenshots of the 'activity' tab in the top right corner:

When the page is first rendered: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMkkb.jpg

When the AJAX event is triggered: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N9lg.jpg

I've tried making sure it's not a hasLayout issue and I even tried JavaScript "correcting" the style of the element on certain events BUT in both cases, IE thinks the "right" value is "5px".

Any ideas what the problem here might be?!

Thanks.

Comment: does your `<body>` have `position:relative`?

Comment: does it need one? If ``body > form > div`` is absolutely positioned and ``<form>`` is not positioned relative, isn't ``<div>`` automatically positioned absolutely within the ``<body>``?

Comment: Could you link to a live sample? This is hard to debug from a screenshot.